# Validate number with optional plus in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I'm trying to validate mobile number between 10 to 12 digits with optional `+` sign

```
Validators.pattern("^((+?))?[0-9]{12}$")
```

but when i enter plus then it is not validation properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"^\+?[0-9]{10,12}$"` or `"^\+?\d{10,12}$"` ?

(Or maybe `"^(\+\d\d)?\d{10}$"` - 12 digits with `+` or only 10 digits? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

this your regex:

```
 ^\+?\d{10,12}$
```

because `+` is part of regex syntex you must exclude it by adding `\` before,
and the `?` symbol mean that is optional

Comment: When i try this i get error :  Invalid regular expression: /^+?d{10,12}$/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: you missing "\" before "d"

Comment: also, `\d` equal to `[0-9]` so you can replce it

Answer (score 0):

**-UPDATE-**

The issue is with the "+" character in the regular expression. In a regular expression, the "+" character is a special character that means "one or more of the preceding character." In this case, the "+" character is not preceded by any other character, so the regular expression is saying "one or more of nothing." To fix the issue, you should escape the "+" character with a "", so that it is treated as a literal "+" character instead of a special character.

Try this regular expression instead: "^((+)?[0-9]{10,12})$"

Also, you should use "?" or {0,1} after the "+" sign if you want it to be optional.

So the final regular expression should be like this:
"^((+)?[0-9]{10,12})$"

**-END OF UPDATE-**

The issue is with the pattern you are using. The "+" character has a special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to escape it in order for it to be treated as a literal character. You can use the "" character to escape it, like this:

Validators.pattern("^((+)?[0-9]{10,12})$")

This pattern will match a string that starts with an optional "+" character, followed by 10 to 12 digits.

Comment: Invalid regular expression: /^((+)?[0-9]{10,12})$/: Nothing to repeat when i use this  `Validators.pattern("^((+)?[0-9]{10,12})$")]`

Answer (score 0):

You need

```js
Validators.pattern(/^\+?\d{10,12}$/)
```

Or

```js
Validators.pattern("\\+?\\d{10,12}")
```

The pattern is simple, `\+?` matches an optional `+` symbol and `\d{10,12}` matches ten, eleven or twelve digits.

The `^` and `$` anchors are only necessary when you use a regex literal notation, `/.../`. When you define the regex as a string literal (`"..."`), you need to bear in mind that the anchors are added automatically by Angular, no need to add them explicitly. Also, the backslashes must be doubled because `\` is used to form string escape sequences (like `\t` for TAB, `\r` for carriage return, etc.) in string literals and a literal backslash is defined with double backslash.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to provide the observation on the `RegEx` `^((+?))?[0-9]{12}$` you mentioned in the post for a better understanding.

- This is not a valid regular expression as `+` should be escaped by using backslash `\`
- No need to mention `?` two times as `+?` will match the optional `+` character.
- As you mentioned `validate mobile number between 10 to 12 digits`, Your `RegEx` will match the exact `12` digits.

Your working `RegEx` should be : `^\+?\d{10, 12}$`

Explanation **:**

`^\+?`: matches optional `+` at the starting of a input string.
`\d`: matches a single digit number `[0-9]`.
`{10, 12}`: matches number between 10 to 12 digits.

Live Demo (Just for a demo purpose I am doing it in a vanilla/plain JavaScript) **:**

```js
function validatePattern() {
    const inputVal = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  if (/^\+?\d{10,12}$/.test(inputVal)) {
    console.log('Valid phone number')
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid phone number')
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="phone" type="text" onBlur="validatePattern()">
```